# What does power series converge p-adically means??

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

What is P-adically and, what does p-adically converge mean?

I have no idea what it is, really. I've trying to google it however, I failed so badly so I had to bring this question.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on $p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) gives a good introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Fractions, written in decimals, can have infinitely many digits after the decimal point.
$p$-adic numbers have infinitely many digits before the decimal point instead.
So instead of 3.1415926535.... you have ...25643.4
The reason for $p$ is that division doesn't work properly in base-10.  Two non-zero numbers can multiply to give zero, which means that division can give more than one answer.  It has to be a prime base instead.  So $p$ is for prime.

Now to converge $p$-adically:  The sequence 
$$1,21,321,2321,12321,212321,...$$ converges $p$-adically to the $p$-adic $...212321$.
The difference between normal decimals depends on the left-most place that they differ - so 1.931 and 1.932 are closer than 1.931 and 1.941.  The further right the first difference, the closer the numbers are together.
The difference between $p$-adics depends on the right-most place that they differ, so ...1221 and ...1121 are closer than ...1221 and ...1231  The further left the first difference, the closer the $p$-adics are together.
If the right-most difference is in the 10s place, the distance is 1/10; if the difference is in the 100s place, the distance is 1/100.
In base $p$, the distances are $1/p$ and $1/p^2$ respectively.

Comment: It is infinitely extended to the left.

Comment: Yes, @AndreasCaranti  Did you read my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. My fault - apologies. Just one question. Are you assuming $p > 3$? Because otherwise $321$ does not appear to be a properly written $p$-adic expansion.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, perhaps the answerer had $p=5$ in mind.